# how should I use [DLLImport("")] in c#?

Tags: c#, dllimport

I have that code, but whene I hover on [DLLImport("wlanapi.dll")] it gives me an error message saying: 'The type or namespace name 'DLLImport' not found (a using directive or an assembly reference is it missing?)'

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace nativewifi
{
    public class Class1
    {
        [DLLImport("wlanapi.dll")]
        public static extern int WlanGetAvailableNetworkList(
            [In] IntPtr clientHandle,
            [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid interfaceGuid,
            [In] WlanGetAvailableNetworkFlags flags,
            [In, Out] IntPtr reservedPtr,
            [Out] out IntPtr availableNetworkListPtr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

C# is a case sensitive language.  The correct name is `DllImport`, with the "L"s being lower case.

Comment: the same probelem remaining!

Comment: the probleme was solved by using .NET framework 4.5.1 insted 4.5